# 8086 Assembly: wrong data reading video memory

Tags: memory, assembly, x86-16

I'm working for a school project on a little game programmed in 8086 Assembly language.
I have to draw on the screen (color some pixels), to do so I use interrupt 10h with mode 13h (ax = 13h). This is a 320px X 200px video mode.

*(Note: you can best read the text underneath with the code opened in another tab (you will better understand what I'm explaining in words))*

**I** want to **first initialize the screen so I'm sure each pixel is black**. To do so I first initialize a palette with black = color number 0.

After that I use a primitive for loop procedure I wrote to initialize the screen (set each pixel black). I pass as arguments respectively the start index (index in video memory (i.e 0 for the first pixel)), the stop index (64 000, last pixel (320px X 200px = 64 000)) and the step size with which the index has to be incremented.

So **all it does is looping from the specified begin adres to the specified stop adres in memory and for each adres putting it on 0** (because black = color number 0 of the palette).

So normally **now every pixel of my screen is black**. Indeed when I launch my little program, the 320x200 video mode appears and the screen is black.

**Further in the program I often** have to **compare the color of a pixel on the screen.** Normally when i acces a certain adress in the video memory it has to be 0 (because I initialized the whole screen on black (color number 0)) except if I colored that pixel with another color.

But when testing my program I found out that **certain pixels were black on the screen** (and since the initialization I never changed their color) **but when I displayed their value, it appeared to be 512 instead of 0**. I can not understand why, since I never changed the color since I initialized them.

I spent hours trying to debug it but I cannot figure out why that pixel suddenly changes from color number 0 of the palette (black) to 512.

Because the pixel with color value 512 is also black on the screen I suppose that is also a value for that color but I want explicitly use color number 0 for black so that I can compare it (because now there is 0 but also 512 for black and maybe other black values).

Relevant part of the code:

```
mov ax, 0a000h ; begin address of video memory
mov es, ax
mov ax, [bp+4][0] ; We put the 1st argument (index) in register ax

mov di, ax
;;;; FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES
mov ax, es:[di]
push ax ; We print the color of the pixel we are checking (normally has to be 0 if that pixel is black on the screen)
call tprint ; 70% of the time the printed color number is 0 but sometimes it prints color number 512 (also a black color but I don't want that, I initialized it to 0!!)
;;;; END DEBUG
;;;; ALSO STRANGE IS THAT WHEN I OUTCOMMENT THESE 3 LINES ABOVE, THE LAST PIXEL OF THE FIRST ROW IS COLORED
;;;; WHEN I LEAVE THESE 3 LINES LIKE NOW (PRINTING THE VALUE OF THAT PIXEL) IT IS THE NEXT PIXEL THAT IS COLORED
;;;; (strange but i don't really care since it was introduced only to debug)

CMP es:[di], 0 ; Comparison to see if the pixel we are checking is black.
; But when it is 512, my program will think it isn't the black color, and will stop executing (because after this call I do a JNZ jump to quit the loop)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You cannot have color 512 in mode 13h (320x200x8bit), because only one byte is used for each pixel, so the unsigned values range from 0 to 255. Without going through your code, I assume that you load zero value from memory to a low 8-bit register (`al`, `bl`, `cl` or `dl`) and have value of 2 in the corresponding high 8-bit register (`ah`, `bh`, `ch`, `dh`) and then in the corresponding 16-bit register (`ax`, `bx`, `cx` or `dx`) you naturally have 512 (2*256+0).

Comment: Why did you remove your code?  Without it, this question and its answers are less valuable to the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nrz hinted, the problem is with data size, although slightly different than what he described. Actually you are loading 2 bytes, so 2 pixels at once instead of 1. You get a value of 512 if a pixel with color 0 is beside a pixel with color 2.

You need to change line 182 to `movzx ax, byte ptr es:[di]` and line 190 to `cmp byte ptr es:[di], 0` (use whatever syntax your assembler supports for byte operations).